# RSA Public and Private keys in string format

Tags: c#

How to use Public and Private RSA keys provided as string for encryption and decryption. as i'm using RSACryptoServiceProvider, it requires XML format, so is there any possibility to use string as provided. Thanks.

Comment: There are many text storage formats for keys, what is the string you need to work with?

Comment: You can convert your string to an XML format Online as well. (If it isn't bound to runtime generation) https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the initial string to get all vectors, public keys, exponents separately. Then convert this strings to byte and use this piece of code as an example:

```
RSAParameters parameters = new RSAParameters();

//here you have to set all provided exponents, vectors
parameters.Exponent = myExponent; //...and other properties

//then - create new RSA cryptoservise provider and import parameters
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSA.ImportParameters(parameters);
```

To convert string to byte use this expression - it's already tested:

```
public static byte[] String2ByteArray(string Hex, int j = -2) =>
(Hex.StartsWith("0x") ? Hex = Hex.Substring(2) : Hex).Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0)
.Select(x => byte.Parse(Hex.Substring(j += 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
public static Action<string> writeOutput = (x) => Debug.WriteLine(x);
```

And if you're given XML like so:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus>…</Modulus>
   <Exponent>…</Exponent>
   <P>…</P>
   <Q>…</Q>
   <DP>…</DP>
   <DQ>…</DQ>
   <InverseQ>…</InverseQ>
   <D>…</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

You can parse this XML to retrieve all the parameters. So assign them to

```
parameters.Modulus
parameters.Exponent
parameters.P
parameters.D
parameters.DP
parameters.DQ
parameters.InverseQ
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, provided string contain only encrypted data no P,Q exponent etc.

Comment: That obviously means, that you can't decrypt encrypted data having only encrypted data without private keys

Comment: Dear Alexey, I mean p,q, exponent exist only in xml string. string I have consist only letters and symbols, I tried olnline conversion it converts to xml public key properly but giving error on provided pkcs#1 and pkcs#8.

Comment: I couldn't quite get you. But maybe after you answer this question I could probably understand you: why you have to use XML?

Comment: as I am using .net to encrypt/decrypt RSACryptoService provider needs keys in xml format

Comment: No, it doesn't neccessary require key to be in XML format (see the explanation above - I edited it).

Comment: Dear Alexey, Thanks for your efforts and replies.

Answer (score 0):

**Having used Bouncy castle dll, pasting key info into text file and using below code i've solved the problem:**

```
public string RSABouncyEncrypt(string content)
        {
            var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
            AsymmetricKeyParameter keyPair;
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"E:\......\public.pem"))
            {
                keyPair = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
            }   

            var engine = new RsaEngine();
            engine.Init(true, keyPair);

            var encrypted = engine.ProcessBlock(bytesToEncrypt, 0, bytesToEncrypt.Length);

            var cryptMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
            //Logs.Log.LogMessage("encrypted: " + cryptMessage);
            //Console.WriteLine(cryptMessage);

            //Decrypt before return statement to check that it has been encrypted correctly
            //RSADecrypt(cryptMessage);
            return cryptMessage;
        }

        public string RSADecrypt(string string64)
        {
            var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(string64); // string to decrypt, base64 encoded

            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;

            using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"E:\.....\private.pem"))
                keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(reader).ReadObject();

            var decryptEngine = new RsaEngine();
            decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);

            var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length));
            //Logs.Log.LogMessage("decrypted: " + decrypted);
            //Console.WriteLine(decrypted);
            return decrypted;
        }
```